# How can I change the default action taken on removable media in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, removable-media

In Ubuntu when I insert a USB stick I get a prompt like:

> You have just inserted a medium with digital photos. Choose
>   application to launch.

Here I can set "perform as default action" and this action is now always taken. But I would like to change the action that is now set as default.

How can do this?

Answer (score 10):

Open "System Settings" and navigate to "Details":

[image]

From there select "Removable Media" from the left pane.  Then you can change what happens when you insert most types of media or turn the prompts off altogether.

[image]

More settings can be found under "Other Media".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can change the default method for handling these events in System Settings -> Details -> Removable Media.

There is a good tutorial here; http://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/